# Creating a view with primary key and distinct column values produces bizarre result

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

```
CREATE VIEW VBrand As select distinct (sBrand), idPartner from tblProduct;
```

Produces this:

```
+-------------------+-----------+
| sBrand            | idPartner |
+-------------------+-----------+
| PLANTERS          |     45933 |
| SARGENTO          |     45933 |
| TOTINOS           |     45933 |
| TRU MOO           |     45933 |
| VANITY FAIR       |     45933 |
| WOOLITE           |     45933 |
| YOPLAIT           |     45933 |
```

But

```
CREATE VIEW VBrand As select distinct sBrand, id, idPartner from tblProduct;
```

Produces this:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
| sBrand   | id       | idPartner |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| NULL     | 13774056 |     45933 |
| PLANTERS | 13774362 |     45933 |
| NULL     | 13774430 |     45933 |
| NULL     | 13774764 |     45933 |
| NULL     | 13774768 |     45933 |
....
```

The view is based on `tblProduct`:

```
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                  | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| idPartner              | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| sBrand                 | varchar(512)        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
```

Why is `distinct COLUMN_NAME` returning a different result when I include the reference table primary key?

I need a primary key because the API Resource expects one.

Answer (score 2):

As a starter: `DISTINCT` is not a function; it applies to all columns of the `SELECT` clause. So this:

```
select distinct (sBrand), idPartner from tblProduct
```

Really means:

```
select distinct sBrand, idPartner from tblProduct
```

Then: what `distinct` does is eliminates duplicate rows in the resultset: the above query gives you all unique brand/partner tuples available in the table.

On the other hand, a primary key column has a different value on each row. As a consequence, putting the primary key key in a `SELECT DISTINCT` query results in all rows of the table being returned.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to apply distinct to only one value? Essentially I want unique brands, but I also want to capture the associated partner val for each unique brand

Comment: @Nina: you would need to explain the logic you want, providing sample data and desired results. I suggest that you ask *a new question* with this information.

Answer (score 0):

The first `select` only chooses distinct values from the two columns sBrand, idPartner, and so you egt only a limited amount of rows

But when you add `id` to the mix every row is different, and so all rows get chosen,because id is an Autoincrment and primary key, which makes it UNIQUE.